# Variable Assignment Issue in Simplified R Code Using map2 Function

Tags: r, bioinformatics, purrr

When I attempted to simplify my code using the map2 function, I encountered a strange issue. Specifically, I couldn't pass variables to the function I was calling. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
library(clusterProfiler)
library(enrichplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(msigdbr)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(GSVA) 
library(GSEABase)


run_enrich = function(gene_symbols,category="C5",subcategory = "GO:BP",title = "",showCategory=10,pvalueCutoff=0.05){
  
  gs = bitr(gene_symbols, fromType="SYMBOL", toType="ENTREZID", OrgDb="org.Hs.eg.db")
  head(gs)
  
  # db <- AnnotationDbi::loadDb(org.Hs.eg_dbfile())
  # on.exit(RSQLite::dbDisconnect(dbconn(db)))
  
  m_t2g <- msigdbr(species = "Homo sapiens", category = category,subcategory = subcategory) %>% 
    dplyr::select(gs_name, entrez_gene)
  head(m_t2g)
  
  cat("\n----run_enrich ",category,"  ",subcategory," ",title,"------\n")
  
  ego.bp = enricher(gene=gs$ENTREZID,TERM2GENE = m_t2g,pAdjustMethod = "BH",pvalueCutoff = pvalueCutoff)
  
  pd = dotplot(ego.bp, showCategory=showCategory,title=title)
  
  enricher_table = ego.bp %>% setReadable( OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db, keyType="ENTREZID") 
  return(list(pd,enricher_table))
}

run_enrich_list = function(gene_symbols,
                           list_category = list(c("C5","GO:BP"),
                                                c("C5","GO:CC"),
                                                c("C5","GO:MF"),
                                                c("C2","CP:KEGG")) ,
                           title = "",showCategory=10,pvalueCutoff=0.05){


  ##---------This is where I've set a breakpoint.
  walk(list_category,print)
  cat("\n ++++++++process",title,"++++++++++++")  
  cat("\n-------01 calculate result------\n")
  list_enrich_result = map(list_category,
                           ~run_enrich(gene_symbols,
                                       category = .x[1],subcategory=.x[2],
                           title=paste0(title,"_",.x[1],"_",.x[2]),
                           pvalueCutoff = pvalueCutoff, showCategory= showCategory))
  

  cat("\n------02 exporing result------\n")
  list_plot = map(list_enrich_result,~.x[[1]])
  list_table = map(list_enrich_result,~.x[[2]])
  return(list(list_plot,list_table))
}

run_enrich_df = function(gene_df,
                         list_category_df = list(c("C5","GO:BP"),
                                                      c("C5","GO:CC"),
                                                      c("C5","GO:MF"),
                                                      c("C2","CP:KEGG"))  ,title = "enrich",
                         showCategory=10,pvalueCutoff=0.05,width = 15,height = 10){

# list_category_df， showCategory，pvalueoff is the same with default parameter
irun_enrich_list = function(gene_col, col_name,
                              list_category = list_category_df,
                              showCategory = showCategory,
                              pvalueCutoff = pvalueCutoff) {
    run_enrich_list(
      gene_symbols = unlist(gene_col),
      title = (paste0('cluster', col_name)),
      list_category = list_category_df,
      showCategory = showCategory,
      pvalueCutoff = pvalueCutoff
    )
}


list_result = map2(
    gene_df, colnames(gene_df),
    ~irun_enrich_list(.x, .y)
  )
  return(list_result )
}
```

In this code, I encountered the following error:

```bash
\u2139 In index: 1.
\u2139 With name: Neuro_c1.
Caused by error in `run_enrich_list()`:
! object '.x' not found
```

I noticed that when I call the 'run_enrich_list' function within 'irun_enrich_list' and use the default parameters, everything works as expected.

```
 run_enrich_list(
  gene_symbols = unlist(gene_col),
  title = (paste0('cluster_', col_name)
)
```

However, when I pass the same default parameters, I observed that 'list_category_df,' 'showCategory,' and 'pvalueCutoff' don't have values at the breakpoint.

Could you help me understand why this issue is occurring and how to fix it?

Additional,I have written the following code in R to loop through the columns of a data frame and store the results in a list:

```
for (i in seq_along(colnames(gene_df))) {
      col_name <- colnames(gene_df)[i]
      gene_col <- gene_df[[i]]
      result <- run_enrich_list(
        gene_symbols = unlist(gene_col),
        title = (paste0("cluster", col_name)),
        list_category = list_category_df,
        showCategory = showCategory,
        pvalueCutoff = pvalueCutoff
      )
      list_result[[col_name]] <- result
    }
```

However, when I run this code, I encounter the following error:

```
Error in run_enrich_list(gene_symbols = unlist(gene_col), title = (paste0("cluster",  : 
  object '"cluster"' not found
```

you can test it is with

```
gene_symbols = tibble("marker" = list(c("S100B","SOX10","GFAP","PLP1")))
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Where is the function `run_enrich_list` from?

Comment: I voted to close because your code is not debuggable if you don't include all of the relevant stuff (see zx's comment above). Please edit it so that I can reproduce the error codes you have

Comment: I have updated the code and description to help you reproduce the error

Comment: you could go further to ensure that a stackoverflow user can copy and paste a single volume of code into a fresh session, and reproduce the issue/error you have. test it yourself to be sure.